# Blocking collection - Remove a specific element

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

I'm using a blocking collection as I need this list to be thread safe:

```
Orders = new BlockingCollection<Order>();
```

I'm trying to remove a specific order, lets say I want to remove `order.ID 1`

if it was a normal collection would be something like

```
orders.Remove(orders.Where(o => o.ID == 1).First());
```

I've read about those collections there is `Take()` and `TryTake()` but none of them allows me to specify which one I want to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, Order>`. In particular its `TryRemove` method takes an ID, removes the entry, and returns the `Order`.

This collection is thread safe, but non blocking. As with `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` keys must be unique (your use of `First` instead of `Single` suggest that constraint might be violated in your case).

Comment: That sounds a good solution for what I want. I'll probably use the order id for the key. My use of `First` on an id suggests I should actually use `Single`. Thanks for you help